# EmberArrayControllers: Is it possible to define a model/content inside the controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Updated With Answer**

I am trying to figure out how to define a model/content inside an EmberArrayController (if that is even possible).

This has been updated to show you how:

**Template**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="#" {{action "sortBy" "id"}} >Id</a></th>
        <th><a href="#" {{action "sortBy" "firstName"}} >First Name</a></th>
        <th><a href="#" {{action "sortBy" "lastName"}} >Last Name</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each}}
        <tr>
            <td>#{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

//Controller.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: Ember.A([{id: 1, firstName: 'Amanda', lastName: 'Hugnkiss'},
                 {id: 2, firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Dover'},
                 {id: 3, firstName: 'Ms.', lastName: 'Cleo'}])
 ,
  actions: {
      sortBy: function(property) {
          //debugger;
          this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
     }
  }
});
```

//Route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  /*model: function(){
      return [
          {id: 1, firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
          {id: 2, firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
          {id: 3, firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
      ];
  }*/
});
```

Based from some of the comments below, this solution works, however, the model hook does not seem to be directly supported as a property or behavior on the EmberArrayController directly, however, the content object property is.

Keep this in mind if opting for this solution.

I will accept this as the answer for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the content (or model), then how about, ummm, setting the model?

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  model: null,

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('model', ['some', 'stuff']);
  }

});
```

Comment: Setting the `content` property is not recommended. It's considered private API and likely will not work the same in the future. You should set the `model` property instead. (The Ember team recently said that they're going to change the way it works soon, but I can't seem to find the post about it.)

Comment: @GJK thanks for pointing that out. Is this the link? https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2007

Comment: So here's where my confusion starts, check out the docs:

I don't see a model property defined here:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Is it just missing?

Comment: `model` === `content` (they are aliases).

Comment: No, it's actually [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4857) issue. So it looks like they've already made some changes to the `content` and `model` properties. As he says, always use `model` and you'll be safe. Also, `model` is defined in the code, but not documented, which is why it doesn't show up in the API. That should probably be fixed.